# How to disable top bar of the iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I would like to remove following top white bar of the onscreen iOS 11 keyboard on my iPad.

> [image: keyboard]

I tried to disable all keyboard options in settings but has no effect.

Such bar appears for example when I open a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) in full web (not a mobile view), search something via input field on the top right corner of the page, then go back and trying to post something to the chat:

> [image: chat]

As you can see this keyboard bar overlaps text input area. So it’s hard to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your keyboard to an alternative keyboard (like [Google Keyboard](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gboard/id1091700242?mt=8)) and change it back to the original keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how to disable it completely but I make it go away by switching to another tab and entering text, then switching back. Works consistently with WhatsApp web on iPad for me. Not the answer but hopefully helpful if anyone else is irritated by it :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently received an iPad as my first Apple device, and several little things like this are making my experience far more cumbersome and irritating, coming from Android.

I found a solution for if you're trying to connect an external keyboard :
For the default keyboard, turn off both Predictive and Shortcuts in Keyboard Settings.
For others(like Gboard), no need to turn off Predictive since they are separate from the default's ones, and don't overlap the view.

If anyone knows a way to have the predicted text bar without having the other bar blocking the view(ex:undocking it), please do help out.

Answer (score -2):

Settings>-General>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Off

Comment: This hides the predictive text features but doesn't affect this white bar.